# Windows is not defined (WinRT.d.ts)

Tags: javascript, typescript, windows-store-apps

I am trying to convert my win store js app into website. Using [this](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2014/05/convert-windows-store-app-to-web-in.html) manual I was able to convert a sample app, but when I tried to convert my application I had problems. The main problem associated with the fact that in a manual author simply cuts out everything related with the variable **Windows**, but I can not do because it is associated with a some functional. I have error:
**Windows is not defined** (https://gyazo.com/bde66f64b67e1dbed7f951c25ea8f1bc). In the application variable "Windows" is taken from the **WinRT.d.ts** file (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/winrt/winrt.d.ts)

How do I include WinRT.d.ts file to my site? Or maybe there are some analogues?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Do you have a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no simple solution to this problem. WinRT - Its a native functionality Windows system and it is not available in the browser. You have to find analogue of your WinRT functionality for browser.